# Modern Reference for Natural Deduction Proof that Logical Extension by Definition is Conservative

Tags: logic, reference-request, definition, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

In logical systems (I'm specifically in the context of language of first order logic) it is possible to extend a theory by adding definitions to compactify/simplify formulas and theorems. It can be proven that, under appropriate (intuitive) conditions these extensions of the language are conservative in that they don't allow for the deduction of any essentially new formulas.

I would like to find a modern reference that demonstrates this proof in a natural deduction context (especially avoiding model theory). Kleene, *Introduction to Metamathematics* (1974) provides a proof of this that I believe satisfies what I am looking for. However, the reference is a bit old and the specific proof I'm looking for is scattered throughout the book. I'm hoping to find another, ideally more modern, reference which is readable and presents the proof clearly.

Comment: For $\Gamma\cup\{\delta\}$ a set of sentences in a language $\Sigma$, $\varphi(x_1,...,x_n)$ an $n$-ary $\Sigma$-formula, and $R$ an $n$-ary relation symbol not in $\Sigma$, suppose $$\Gamma\cup\{\forall x_1,...,x_n(\varphi(x_1,...,x_n)\leftrightarrow R(x_1,...,x_n))\}\vdash\delta$$ is a valid sequent. In any reasonable derivation system given a derivation $\pi$ of this sequent we can produce a new derivation $\eta$ of $$\Gamma\cup\{\forall x_1,...,x_n(\varphi(x_1,...,x_n)\leftrightarrow\varphi(x_1,...,x_n))\}\vdash\delta$$ by just replacing "$R$" with "$\varphi$" throughout $\pi$. (continued)

Comment: This can be proved by induction on the complexity of the original derivation $\pi$ (note that it does take a bit of care to correctly make "replace each "$R$" by "$\varphi$"" precise). And now eliminating the additional hypothesis "$\forall x_1,...,x_n(\varphi(x_1,...,x_n)\leftrightarrow\varphi(x_1,...,x_n))$" is easy since it's a tautology. Introducing definitions of *functions* or *elements* adds some tedium to this since we have to meaningfully play with the syntax of sentences, but it's fundamentally no harder.

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes, that’s exactly the proof I’d like a reference for. I understand the general gist you describe but I would like to see the details described, both for how to do the replacement and for defining functions. Maybe it’s too simple to appear in a textbook? Doesn’t feel that way to me!

Comment: Actually, I overstated the difficulty of the replacement in the relations-only case. For each formula in the original deduction, replace each substring of the form "$R(t_1,...,t_n)$" for $t_0,...,t_n$ terms with the string resulting from substituting $t_i$ for $x_i$ in $\varphi$. That's all there is to it. Maybe it will help if you can give a specific point of nontriviality in the argument?

Comment: Life is a little bit harder if you want to define functions. This is something that certainly ought to appear in textbooks, but seems to get brushed aside. I had a recollection that it was at least mentioned in either Mendelson or Boolos and Jeffrey, but I am not sure about that. If you only need to deal with functions that are uniquely determined by their arguments, then a syntactic proof of conservativity can be given but it involves contextual transformations. Dealing with loosely defined functions requires semantic methods or some chicanery.

Comment: @RobArthan I had come across the Mendelson reference before also and it looks like it does have relevant sections as well. Also some newer editions. Haven't investigated Boolos and Jeffrey. Could you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: @NoahSchweber When I've spent more time on the problem I will post another question if need help with any specific nontrivialities.

Comment: I've posted a slightly extended version of my comment as an answer, having checked the references. They are far from ideal, I am afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Life is a little bit harder if you want to define functions. This is something that certainly ought to appear in textbooks, but seems to get brushed aside. There is some relevant information in Mendelson's *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (see "definition, possible" in the index) or Boolos, Burgess and Jeffrey's *Computation and Logic* (see discussion of elimination of names and function symbols). If you only need to deal with functions that are uniquely determined by their arguments, then a syntactic proof of conservativity can be given but it involves contextual transformations. Dealing with loosely defined functions requires semantic methods or some chicanery.

[Aside: my versions of the cited books are ancient hence I haven't given page or section references as they will be out of date.]